# Excel Protected View triggering on Valid Spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Our organization has an Excel file that has been around for quite some time. I released a new version of this to users, and roughly 50% of users are getting an error "Protected View Office has detected a problem with this file. Editing it may harm your computer. Click for more details."

See: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/what-is-protected-view-HA010355931.aspx

The former page suggestions that file validation failed.

I downloaded this BFFValidator tool: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2011/07/13/bffvalidator-tool-goes-public.aspx

The result: PASSED.

It is too complicated to recreate. I would update to a save in a more modern format but there are still some users on Excel 2003. We have no control over the group policy, registry values, etc of the users computers.

Has anyone experienced this or found a solution?